# How to create a diamond-inheritance in pgf-umlcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pgf-umlcd

### Situation

I want to create different class diagrams, especially one that shows a [diamond problem in multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

Since it seemed especially easy to use I decided to go with `pgf-umlcd` but that led to this ...

### Problem

When creating such diamond inheritance LaTeX wont let me compile the `pgf-umlcd`-diagram. I was only able to create the desired result with the workaround shown in the MWE.

Moreover, I've tried other diagrams that resulted in the same error (i.e. the example shown [here in 1.2.2](https://github.com/xuyuan/pgf-umlcd/blob/master/pgf-umlcd-manual.pdf), [code here](https://github.com/xuyuan/pgf-umlcd/blob/master/demo/multiple-inheritance.tex)).

> How to create multiple inheritance diagrams in pgf-umlcd ?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}[text width=1.5cm]{Dog}{0,0}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Labrador}{-1.75,-1.5}
\inherit{Dog}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Poodle}{1.75,-1.5}
\inherit{Dog}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Labradoodle2}{0,-3}
%\inherit{Poodle}
\inherit{Labrador}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Labradoodle}{0,-3}
\inherit{Poodle}
%\inherit{Labrador} % uncomment for error
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**edit:**
as an additional note: I found the linked pdf to be compileable with the corresponding (*online available*) version of `pgf-umlcd` ([github repository](https://github.com/xuyuan/pgf-umlcd) as a whole works as is). Where the versions only differ in two lines between line 194 and 208 of the `pgf-umlcd.sty`-file (see lines 4 and 10 in the excerpts):

github = good (from manual: May 31, 2015)

```
%% connections
\begin{pgfonlayer}{connectionlayers}
\ifnum\c@umlcdClassAbstractClassNum>0
\foreach \c in {\umlcdClassAbstractClass}{
  \draw [umlcd style inherit line] (\c) -- (\umlcdClassName);
}
\fi

\ifnum\c@umlcdClassInterfaceNum>0
\foreach \c in {\umlcdClassInterface}{
  \draw [umlcd style implement line] (\c) -- (\umlcdClassName);
}
\fi
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

installed = bad (from manual: January 31, 2012; installed via TeX Live Utility)

```
%% connections
\begin{pgfonlayer}{connectionlayers}
\ifnum\c@umlcdClassAbstractClassNum>0
\foreach \c in \umlcdClassAbstractClass {
  \draw [umlcd style inherit line] (\c) -- (\umlcdClassName);
}
\fi

\ifnum\c@umlcdClassInterfaceNum>0
\foreach \c in \umlcdClassInterface {
  \draw [umlcd style implement line] (\c) -- (\umlcdClassName);
}
\fi
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

both say `\ProvidesPackage{pgf-umlcd}[2011/10/01 v0.3dev Some LaTeX macros for UML Class Diagrams.]` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've kind of answered your own question. If you don't want to use the version from GitHub, you can use `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` to patch `\endclassAndInterfaceCommon`, removing the extra braces:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\endclassAndInterfaceCommon}
{{\umlcdClassInterface}}
{\umlcdClassInterface}
{}{}

\patchcmd{\endclassAndInterfaceCommon}
{{\umlcdClassAbstractClass}}
{\umlcdClassAbstractClass}
{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{class}[text width=1.5cm]{Dog}{0,0}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Labrador}{-1.75,-1.5}
\inherit{Dog}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Poodle}{1.75,-1.5}
\inherit{Dog}
\end{class}

\begin{class}[text width=3cm]{Labradoodle}{0,-3}
\inherit{Poodle}
\inherit{Labrador} 
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not really want to answer myself and thought there might be a better solution than just putting the git file in the path. With your answer I and maybe others could learn something new; thanks.